# Geocoding services offline and online

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, bing-maps

Currently I'm searching for a geocoding service which I can use on different project. When a project starts we get a list of addresses from our clients and the first thing we need to do is to gelocate them.
In the past we have used mappoint to get the most of them correct, around 85%, after this, we use online services to determine the rest (these are dataset of 30k entries).

- Offcourse I looked to google maps but this service can only be used
  when the found lat/lng are used in google maps.
- Open street maps does not support housenumbers (Belgium, the Netherlands).
- Mapquest has an ok api, but the first results I have tested return a bogus result.
- The data scienentist toolkit also returned a result, but the results
  were not accurate (1 precision digit)
- openaddresses.org is not responding...
- cloudmade does not return correct addresses in belgium/netherlands

We do have a ms mappoint licence but this is only addressable via vba and we are working with Java. Could you point out directions I still have to explore to build a durable geocoding solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [Deutsche Post](http://www.postadressglobal.com/about-postadress-global/) offers address correction services for [Belgium](http://www.postadressglobal.com/country/belgium/postal-correction-of-belgian-addresses/) and [the Netherlands](http://www.postadressglobal.com/country/netherlands/formatting-and-structure-of-dutch-addresses/).

The formatting and structuring of your address data is an important factor in achieving the best results when it comes to data maintenance, such as modification, updating, and correction.

A Dutch consumer address is structured as follows:

```
De heer Jan Voogt
Overtoom 74
9203 PA Drachten
```

A Dutch company address is structured as follows:

```
Musterfirma Holding B.V.
Postbus 102
3890 AN Zeewolde
```

The address standardisation and cleansing process allows for the correct breakdown of an address into name, street, house number, postcode and area, as well as the correct allocation of postcodes and districts. Any incorrectly written names of streets and districts (which can often occur as a result of multilingualism) are also standardised.

Comment: This is not very useful because it does not contribute to my original goal to automate the geocoding. I should send all my addresses to the deutsche post to get them cleansed and then use them for geocoding.

Comment: @jelle: Yes.  How can you be sure the geocoding is correct unless the addresses are correct?  We have this problem in the United States with addresses like 1380 West, 1100 South, Orem UT.  I guarantee you that you can't geocode that address correctly.

Comment: This is true but the quality of my addresses is already verified because we have another process for doing this.